# ¿Por qué me ignora la validación del email de un input?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `formulario`, al hacer click en el `botón` guardar, con `javascript` valido que no haya campos vacíos, que las dos contraseñas sean iguales y DEBERÍA checkear que la dirección de email sea correcta, pero no me funciona.

aca mi `formulario`

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegistrarUsuario", "Usser", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "f1" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="cont-formulario">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblName">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" name="txtName" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" maxlength="45" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblApe">Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSurname" name="txtSurname" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" maxlength="45" placeholder="Apellido" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblDate">Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtDateBirth" name="txtDateBirth" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" placeholder="DateBirth" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblEmail">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" maxlength="45" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblUserName">Nombre de usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUsserName" name="txtUsserName" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" maxlength="45">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblPwd">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtClave1" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" id="clave1" maxlength="45" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblPwd">Repita la contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtClave2" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" id="clave2" maxlength="45" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblDom">Domicilio:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" placeholder="Domicilio" maxlength="45">
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="checkData()">Guardar</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

aca el código `javascript`

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function checkData() {
            //obteniendo el valor de los input de las contraseñas
            clave1 = document.f1.txtClave1.value
            clave2 = document.f1.txtClave2.value
            valor = document.f1.txtEmail.value;

            if (clave1 != clave2)
                alert("Las dos contraseñas son distintas!.\nLas contraseñas deben ser iguales!")
            else if (validarCamposInput()) // Solo se enviará si los campos están bien
                document.f1.submit()//pulsa el submit y manda los datos del form

            //Other Sentences
        }

        function ValidateEmail(txtEmail) {
            if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(f1.txtEmail.value)) {
                return (true)
            }
            alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
            return (false)
        }

        // function ValidateEmail(txtEmail) {
        //     var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        //     if (txtEmail.match(mailformat)) {
        //         document.f1.txtEmail.focus();
        //         return true;
        //     }
        //     else {
        //         alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
        //         document.f1.txtEmail.focus();
        //         return false;
        //     }
        // }

        var mensajeCabecera = "Los siguientes campos están vacíos:\n";
        var mensajeValidacion = "";

        function validarCamposInput() {
            mensajeValidacion = "";

            $(".form-group > input").each(function () {
                if (this.value == "") {
                    mensajeValidacion = mensajeValidacion + (this.id).replace("txt", "") + "\n";
                    $("#" + this.id).addClass('bordeRojoValidacion');
                }
            });

            if (mensajeValidacion == "") {
                // No hay mensaje de error, quiere decir que los campos están correctos
                // Devolver verdadero
                return true;
            }
            alert(mensajeCabecera + mensajeValidacion);
            // Hay error en los campos
            // Devolver falso
            return false;
        }

        function validarInput(caracter) {
            if (caracter != "") {
                $("#" + caracter.id).removeClass('bordeRojoValidacion');
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes `validarInput` en  el campo email, deberia ser `ValidateEmail`

Answer (score 0):

No veo que hagas una llamada al método ValidateEmail. De la misma manera, el botón para guardar información debería ser de tipo submit.